# How can I record 5-8 SD A/V inputs on Linux?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, nvidia-graphics-card, video-conversion

I would like to be able to record 5-8 video channels on a linux computer.

While the videos are being recorded I would like to break them into 1-2 hour pieces and back them up.

The source of videos is 24/7 for a few days and I cannot afford to lose video.

I have seen a number of solutions but standard security cctv DVRs/NVRs tend to make you use their software to download video files (even if you try to back the video files up on a NAS).

Are there other possible solutions to this problem?

RCA to USB connecters can only be recorded one at a time (I think) and certain frame grabbers tend to record uncompressed video which would be too computationally expensive to encode when it's a multi channel feed on a single linux machine. Nvidia might be able to encode videos fast but I'm not sure how many channels of raw video it can do at the same time.

Comment: @Mokubai I have re-worded the question, please do see if this is better :)

Comment: Suits me fine, your original question might still work on [hardwarerecs.se] though.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"A/V"* and *"video"*?  Do you mean CVBS composite video, which is low quality and old tech?  Modern cameras have embedded microprocessors, and digitize, encode, and compress the hi-res video into a data stream (e.g. IP cameras).  *"RCA to USB connecters..."* -- A nonsense description.  RCA connectors can be used for analog audio, or digital audio, or composite video, or component video.  Specifying only the connector type instead of the proper signal name (and omitting the functionality of the device) is usually a sign that you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific, I've only been doing this for a few months with no progress. Yes I mean CVBS composite video, the source of video is a set top box. @sawdust

Comment: *"the source of video is a set top box"* -- So you have a stack of 5 to 8 STBs?

Comment: @sawdust Yes. :) I'm hoping that I can be guided a little better now.

Comment: Composite video is analog SD video.  (BTW "SD" can also be digital.)  For a PC to "record" analog video, the video has to be digitized, encoded, and typically compressed.  Hardware for analog video is typically old tech, and would generate MPEG2 rather than H.264.  I.E. NTSC (or PAL) to H.264 converter/encoders are more expensive than MPEG2 units.    You would need one video converter/encoder  per STB.  You could probably attach only a few USB2.0-based converters/encoders  before you saturated the bus.  Do not expect a GPU to help solve this.

Comment: @sawdust So could I find cheap NTSC/PAL to MPEG2, and then convert the MPEG2 files to MP4?

'USB2.0-based converters/encoders before you saturated the bus' This means on one linux machine even if I attached a usb hub I would not be able to input many feeds?

Also what is the best software bet to capture multiple video feeds on Linux?

Comment: Over 6 years ago someone described his PC with 5 or more digital TV tuners, and recording SD contant.  With an up-to-date PC, 8 channels of std def MPEG2 should be possible. A USB hub is the worst possible approach, and guaranteed to fail.  Encoders on PCIe adapters would have the best performance.  I doubt that you can get a PC to do more than one realtime transcoding.